# Looking for an Offline Scanning Software like Neat Desk

Tags: windows, document-management, scanning

Looking for a new scanning software that I can use that will allow me the following

1. Be usable fully offline (a must), ideally no cloud integration
2. allow password protection to access some if not all documents
3. Document organization and filing grouping are needed. (receipts, bills, warranty etc)
4. OCR and searchable would be a big plus
5. one time purchase versus a subscription
6. Usable with a wide variety of scanners
   ​

I know this will be like trying to find a golden goose of scanning software, but I have to believe that there is a company of solution out there with something like this. I loved the neat desk software for a long time, but it is clearly dated, and the scanner is on its last legs at this point. I am looking for something for personal use, but I have like 5 filing cabinets worth of personal docs that I am trying to digitize and sort. This will be a big library of docs when I am done.

​Looking for Windows 10, open ended on pricing, I would say $300 is my cap. Yes I am looking for document managing if there is a better solution to combine with a normal scanning software that is Ok as well. IE if two programs would be a better solution that is OK as well.

This will be for a single machine, I do not need it networked, nor will I be accessing the documents from another machine.

Ideally it would have a good backup solution as well, so that documents can be recovered if there is some sort of catastrophic hardware failure.

On paper Sohodox looks like something that fits this, but I have never heard of the company but will trial it, but I want to see if anyone knows of something better.

Comment: This is the best thing I have found so far, want to see if there is anything better: http://www.sohodox.com/

Comment: What OS must it run on, and how much you'd be willing to pay if needed? Also, reading your requirements, you not only want a scanning software – but rather a full-fledged document management system (DMS/CMS), is that correct? Shall that run on a "central machine" with clients accessing it from multiple machines (i.e. client-server-model) – or rather on a single machine where users log in to locally?